# Woocommerce display products in html table

Tags: html, woocommerce, html-table

I'm trying to display a list of WooCommerce products in a normal html table. These products really are simple products; each contains a product name, two custom fields (mass & dimensions), and an 'add to quote' button. This is all that will be displayed on the front-end.

In loop-start.php I've added the opening `<table>` tag. In loop-end.php I've added the closing `</table>` tag. But, when the front-end page is loaded and you look at the source, each product has its own `<table>` and `</table>` tags. I'd like to have only one table...

loop-start.php:

```
<table> <?php echo (function_exists('sometheme_woo_shop_columns_class') ? sometheme_woo_shop_columns_class() : ''); ?>">
```

loop-end.php:

```
</table>
```

content-product.php:

```
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>
<tr>
<td>        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></td>



        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>
<td>        <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_mass_field', true );  ?></td>
<td>        <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_dimensions_field', true ); ?></td>
<td>

    <?php

        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); 

    ?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Source of front-end products page:

```
<div class="relative-container">...</div>
<div cass="boxed layout boxed colors</div>
<table>...</table>
<div class="relative-container">...</div>
<div cass="boxed layout boxed colors</div>
<table>...</table>
<div class="relative-container">...</div>
<div cass="boxed layout boxed colors</div>
<table>...</table>
<div class="relative-container">...</div>
<div cass="boxed layout boxed colors</div>
<table>...</table>
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as I've been searching for this solution for a while (prior to posting the question), I'll post the solution here in case someone else needs the same.

The problem: Wordpress auto formatting inserts `<table>` and `</table>` tags when it generates the front-end. As such, the solution is to disable Wordpress auto formatting. Adding this line to functions.php does the trick:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

However, that'll disable auto formatting globally. I just want it to happen when the products page is generated. A solution is to create a function which is called before the shop page output:

```
function remove_wp_autoformatting () {
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }

add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'remove_wp_autoformatting');
```

For the sake of full disclosure, I'm still a novice. So, if anyone has a more efficient solution, it'd be much appreciated.